# why I don't get the content array result 0,1,2?

Tags: javascript

I have a code:
[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/GEnPf/12/)

which loop three times, each time creating a new function that returns the loop sequence number.

I expected to see the loop sequence inser to array : **0, 1, and 2.**

```
a[i] = function() {
            return i;
        }
```

everything looks normal but when I try to print the array I got

the resualt:

```
arr[0] is =>function () { return i; }
arr[1] is =>function () { return i; }
arr[2] is =>function () { return i; }
```

the code:

```
function f() {
    var a = [];
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        a[i] = function() {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return a;
}
var arr = f();

for (var index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
    document.write("<b>arr[" + index + "] is </b>=>" + arr[index] + "<br>");
}​
```

why I don't get the resualt **0, 1, and 2.** ?

many thx.

Comment: Because the variable "i" - **which all the functions share** - is just a single variable, and using it in those functions does not "freeze" its value.  Each function will return the value of "i" as it stands when the function call is made, **not** what it was when the function was created.

Comment: [Demo jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/GEnPf/12/) I try it

Comment: Corrections to your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GEnPf/13/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `a[i]` is a function, not the returned value from the function. So basically you are filling your array with three function bodies, so when you retrieve any of them, you are getting back the body of the function.  You can try to do `a[i].call()` to call the function returned but then you'd get 3 for each invocation, which in line with what Pointy has pointed out in the comment. Because that was the last value when the loop was called, i became 3 right before the loop stopped

See [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gj4ms/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand why you expected all array elements to return the value `i` had at the time the function was constructed. Which isn't that big of a leap, but each and every of those functions share a single scope. The values aren't linked to the created functions, it's the scope that outlives the *"mother"* function. In this scope there is a single variable called `i` that is incremented until it's `3`. The only thing you could do, if you really, *really* want to use a closure is this:

```
function f()
{
    var a = [];
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        a[i] = (function(currentI)
        {//create a separate scope, pass current value of i to it
            return function()
            {
                return currentI;
            }
        })(i);
    }
    return a;
}
var arr = f();
for (var index = 0; index < arr.length; index++)
{
    document.write("<b>arr[" + index + "] is </b>=>" + arr[index]() + "<br>");
}​
```

This produces the expected result, [as you can see here](http://jsfiddle.net/GEnPf/14/)

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, if you *truly* wanted an array with three functions where each returns  values of `i` as they were at the time the function was created, you just need to pass in a copy of `i` when you assign your function to `a[i]`:

```
function f() {
    var a = [];
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        a[i] = (function(n) {
            return function() {
                return n;
            };
        }(i));
    }
    return a;
}

var arr = f();

for (var index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
    document.write("<b>arr[" + index + "]() is </b>=> " + arr[index]() + "<br>");
}​
```

Outputs:

> arr[0]() is => 0
>   arr[1]() is => 1
>   arr[2]() is => 2

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mc86T/)